# Two to one Analog to Digital conversion

Tags: integrated-circuit, signal-processing, modulation

I am measuring two DC biosignals but have only one input channel. I was wondering if some type of signaling or modular simple trick might be used to 'interleave' the signals while also digitizing them. For example, I might sample the first analog signal at 3600 Hz and sample the second at 3600 Hz as well, switching off between each source... Then what?

What I am really asking for is how to fit undersample (relatively) in order to output two signals in one channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an analogue multiplexer like the DG308 (or similar): -

[image]

It has four analogue switches and each can be digitally controlled. So, one input can feed to (say) D1 and the other input to D2. Then join together S1 and S2 and you have a change over switch that routes either signal 1 or signal 2 to the common connection of S1/S2.

Next, you use an analogue to digital converter (ADC) on the common signal.

But, you can buy plenty of ADCs combined with an input multiplexer to save you all the hassle of two chips.

Comment: Can I demultiplex this signal later on to get the originals back?

Comment: Once digitized you can choose to handle the two combined signals as you wish. Ultimately you may want to have two digital to analogue converters or just one (which can then be de-interleaved in the analogue domain with a multiplexer in the same way.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't need/want my signal to need control by digital means. For example, a microprocessor is out of the question. Is there anyway I could get a device or passive RC-circuit like thing that would alternate between each switch at a certain frequency and also leave each signal on for a certain amount of time? Is there a way, using resistors transistors and capacitors, that a circuit like this might be designed?

Comment: I may have found the answer to this latter question here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC